# ZebraDesigner 3 - What are the .default and .variables formats that available on the print screen?

Tags: printing, file-format, zebra-printers, barcode-printing

Has anyone used the ZebraDesign 3 and tried to Load the .default or .variables files? Are they used to connect the data on import, or are these formats that allow you to import the default values for the Variable Data?

Here are the screenshots where the import can be found:

[image: Formats Dropdown menu]

[image: Load button on the Printing screen]

I have tried to format them as csv files, tab divided and new line divided. No error is shown on import and no value is added to the list..

Wonder if there is a hidden functionality here, or if it is just limited by the Essentials version of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the variable names in: Item Properties -> General.
Then fill the file with rows like `variablename=variablecontent`.

[sample content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tHmS.png)

Comment: That is amazing! Works perfectly and opens up a great opportunity to import data without complex linking! Thank you!